# Logging into Stack Overflow with Mechanize and Python

Tags: python, mechanize

I have been using this guide to help me: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet/

I want to log into Stack Overflow and print out my login response using Mechanize in Python. I have been troubleshooting to find a form name to select and enter my information into, but am currently getting an error "ValueError: at least one argument must be supplied to specify control" because I am trying to print out all forms and controls to help me figure out what I need to choose from.

```
   import mechanize

   #make browser object
   browser = mechanize.Browser()

  #open stack login page
  browser.open("http://stackoverflow.com/users/login#login-in")

  #print all the forms on the page
  print("\n Printing all forms on page...\n")
  for form in browser.forms():
          print("Form Name:", form.name)
          print form
  print("\n Done printing forms...\n")

  #printing the controls of each form

  browser.form=list(browser.forms())[0]

  print("\n Printing controls of form 0 \n")
  for control in browser.form.controls:
          print control
          print "type=%s, name=%s, value=%s" % (control.type, control.name, browser[control.name])

  browser.form=list(browser.forms())[1]

  print("\n Printing controls of form 1 \n")
  for control in browser.form.controls:
          print control
          print "type=%s, name=%s, value=%s" % (control.type, control.name, browser[control.name])

  browser.form=list(browser.forms())[2]

  print("\n Printing controls of form 2 \n")
 for control in browser.form.controls:
          print control
          print "type=%s, name=%s, value=%s" % (control.type, control.name, browser[control.name])

 print("\n Done printing all controls \n")
```

It looks like there are 3 forms on the page, but they do not contain the email and password inputs I am looking for to login. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login forms for SO appear to use extensive JavaScript. Note that all of the buttons related to login on the page you posted call JavaScript functions. `mechanize` can not execute JavaScript and therefore won't show the content you need.

You could drive a browser using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) with [Python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).  You could also switch to doing everything in JavaScript using [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it to work with Selenium, just have to do some editing!